# Django Heroku deployment errors

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy a web application and came across this issue where it says that it could not build wheels for myproject and that the runner is empty. I am just confused because I did not name it myproject on Heroku or VSCode. Is there something I might have done that made it register in this way? Regardless, I am trying to get over this roadblock so i can deploy it.

```
remote:          Building wheel for myapp (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for myapp: filename=myapp-0.1.dev0-py3-none-any.whl size=1166 sha256=ec655f854ab6a2c0ba6b36dda552a60e1b54af84d93a82785eda9229258b686c
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7q7p2y16/wheels/8b/36/8b/cb810ee2b64417af5f91d361665839bd04414f112ecafcb1e0
remote:          Building wheel for myproject (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for myproject (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
remote:          
remote:          × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
remote:          │ exit code: 1
remote:          ╰─> [3 lines of output]
remote:              warning: build_scripts: runner is an empty file (skipping)
remote:              
remote:              error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/scripts-3.9/runner'
remote:              [end of output]
remote:          
remote:          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for myproject
remote:          Running setup.py clean for myproject
remote:          Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for mysqlclient: filename=mysqlclient-2.1.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=111030 sha256=49d3fa22bdee98908b60480596a037767f537fbf8b49bb072cc5c8d34ffb316d
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7q7p2y16/wheels/f3/a5/27/c6312d8008951cfd5511684378a9e057b82006c70e1fea6107
remote:          Building wheel for package-json (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for package-json (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for package-json: filename=package_json-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=973 sha256=c8a566bdfde95f06be1f9b9a56cb382a3d31341766307f5f3a06f57ee6f4c407
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7q7p2y16/wheels/2b/57/9d/11d9ad6489a2dd76a6503ea4f8bc0d853e5fbe151b3308b282
remote:        Successfully built myapp mysqlclient package-json
remote:        Failed to build myproject
remote:        ERROR: Could not build wheels for myproject, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to journallove.
```

I do not have a setup.py either so I'm guessing that this is another system process but I'm not entirely sure. I tried updating the wheels with pip and that didnt work either.